# Can someone explain jQuery's addEvents feature?

Tags: jquery, events, mootools

I saw this code on someone else's website, but found no reference to it on jQuery's site.

```
window.addEvents({
  'domready': resizer,
  'resize': resizer
});
```

Can either: someone point me to the documentation for `addEvents` or explain to me how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not jQuery. It's [MooTools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element:addEvents).

The equivalent in jQuery would be:

```
$(window).bind({
    load: resizer,
    resize: resizer
});
```

[`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) accepts a map of event names to handler functions.

Comment: @Ashley - The jQuery version turned out to be rather close, so it's all good :). @Reigel - I feel really guilty now and will delete my answer as soon as it gets a mere 10000000000000 votes :P